# Trying to build simple android but have a schema issue Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xml, xamarin

I'm trying to run a simple android app on VS 2015 and using Xamarin & C#.

I'm a bit confused - is this URL supposed to link to an existing/live schema file because the link is broken? http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android

My buttons on the app have their own xml files(for styling purposes) and the header looks as follow: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">`

I'm getting error messages in my console - where is states: `Could not find schema information for the element ...` Thus meaning my elements aren't getting the style their supposed to. I presume this is all happening because the link above is not linking correctly?

Any help will be appreciated a lot!

Answer (score 0):

No, that's just a default schema NAME, it does not need to work as an available URL, your problem could be an error calling the proper XML style sheet for your controls. If you need an example please check this [link](http://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/resources/general/style_a_button/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That is actually the tutorial that I'm following at the moment. I've read through it multiple times to make sure it's all correct but can't find out what the problem is.